# fgets in C program exits abruptly

Tags: c, fgets

Why does the following code upon running exits abruptly without printing any output???

```
FILE *file;

file=fopen("filename","r");
 char *line;
 while (fgets(line,1000,file)!=NULL) {
   int i=0;
    int l=sizeof(line);
    printf("%d\n",l);
  }
```

Comment: Where do the 1000 come from? In other words, where are the 1000 chars that should hold the line data? You have only an uninitialised pointer pointing nowhere legal.

Comment: @MOehm This is a part of my code,file is stream for a file which has multiple lines.Each line can have a max of 1000 chars

Comment: Yes, I can see your intention, but you need to store the line in an array, so you need `char line[1000]`. That will give you 1000 chars to store the line. (Or keep `char *line` and `malloc` like Haris suggested. But then you have to `free` it later.) `fgets` does not auto-allocate the memory for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *line;
```

this is a char pointer, not pointing to any memory..

```
fgets(line,1000,file)!=NULL
```

and here you are trying to store the string that you read from `file` in it, without allocating memory to it

to correct that, before you do the `fgets()` do a `malloc()` to allocate memory

```
line = malloc(1000);
```

or, declare the `line` variable as a char array, like this

```
char line[1000];
```

Comment: @harris Thanks a lot it worked,but still value of l is printed 4 for every line even if in my file the length of no line is  4

Comment: Because sizeof is not meant to measure string lengths. Use strlen.

Answer (score 1):

Your program says: Read a bunch of data out of a file, and write it over a random part of the program memory (stack, heap, code, whatever...). Not a good thing.

One way to fix, change `char *line` to `char line[1000+1]`

There is no need to use a pointer or dynamic allocation here.

Second bug, don't use `sizeof(line)` when referring to a pointer. It doesn't work like you think. strlen(line) is more appropriate. In general, you are better of using a common constant to allocate the buffer size and read from the file.

```
const int MAXLINESIZE = 1000;

char line[MAXLINESIZE+1];

fgets(line, MAXLINESIZE, file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the new secure way of reading the size of an array. This only reads an array so you will know that it is an array and not a pointer. Its a built in security feature.

```
#include "stdlib.h"  // _countof() definition location

// unlike sizeof, _countof works here for both narrow- and wide-character strings.

 _TCHAR arr[20], *p; 

//sizeof(arr) = 40 bytes 
//_countof(arr) = 20 elements

// In C++, the following line would generate a compile-time error:    
// printf( "%d\n", _countof(p) ); 
// error C2784 (because p is a pointer)
```

You can see that _countof(array name) is a much better choice if you plan to use C. Also it is not effected by Wide-Characters; returns the correct amount of elements in an array, unlike sizeof().